# Web service randomly not getting response

Tags: web-services, timeout, xamarin.ios

In my Monotouch application I consume a web service. This service is written in VS2010 running on a windows server using https with load balancing distributed onto two nodes. My problem is that sometimes when I call a method on my instance of this web service it does not get any response and is still waiting till it crashes on timeout. This seems to happen randomly on all of the services methods. My guess is that it is somehow related to monotouch networking but I am not successful with googling.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem when using the WebClient class in MonoTouch. I blogged about it here: http://escoz.com/webclient-reliability-problems-under-monotouch/

At the time, my solution was to use the NSUrlRequest class in MonoTouch instead of the .NET client.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will read documentation about this to see if I can use it with soap web services.

Comment: Where you ever able to get this working with SOAP?  I am having a similar problem.

Comment: @scotru this is an old question, most of the networking stuff in monotouch has been updated since then.. Yes, I was able to get SOAP working then, but it's been a long time, sorry I can't help much.